# Javascript object remove nesting

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am have an object that looks like this in the console,

`res.local.details > Object {role-details : {} }`

so to access this I would need to do `res.local.details['role-details']`

Is is possible to make it so I can "explode" `role-details` into `details` so I can just do

`res.locals.details`

to access the attributes from role-details

Comment: Maybe `res.local.details = { ...res.local.details['role-details'] }` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, objects in JS are mutable. If you want to reassign data from one part of your object to another, you can just do it like this:

```
const myObj = {
    name: {
        first: 'John',
        last: 'Smith',
    },
    address: {
        streetNo: '123',
        streetName: 'Main St',
        city: {
            name: 'Exampletown'
        }
    }
}

myObj.address.city.name  // resolves to Exampletown

myObj.address.city = myObj.address.city.name

myObj.address.city /// resolves to Exampletown
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in several ways.

In this particular case, where `details` just has that one property, you can just do:

```
res.local.details = res.local.details['role-details'];
```

In a more generic situation, `details` might have other properties that you don't want to destroy with this operation. In that case you can use:

```
Object.assign(res.local.details, res.local.details['role-details']);
```

With this, `res.local.details` will keep all its properties (provided they don't have the same name as properties of `role-details`), including `role-details` (but which becomes kind of obsolete).

The same can be achieved with:

```
res.local.details = {...res.local.details, ...res.local.details['role-details']};
```